# Is there any difference between <?=$value?> and <? echo $value; ?>

Tags: php

Environment: Windows/7 + Apache/2.2.21 + PHP/5.3.8

File contents of `test.php`:

```
hello, <?=$test?>
```

File contents of `index1.php`:

```
<?php
$test = 'world';

require './test.php';
?>
```

File contents of `index2.php`:

```
<?php
global $test;
$test = 'world';

require './test.php';
?>
```

Output of `index1.php` is:

```
hello,
```

Output of index2.php is:

```
hello, world
```

When the contents of `test.php` is:

```
hello, <? echo $test; ?>
```

Output of `index1.php` and `index2.php` both are:

```
hello, world
```

So, my question is: Is there any difference between `<?=$test?>` and `<? echo $test; ?>` ?

Comment: Is that really all that's in `test.php`? There's no function or other scope limiting structure?

Comment: @Scott That's what the title says

Comment: @Charlie The title was edited, it didn't say that at first.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of `index1.php` or it didn't happen.

Comment: Sorry for all, it's my fault, not reading the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference. Only one I think about is that `<?` is considered as short tag and might not work.

Comment: Although I am not the downvoter. But your two sentences are contradictory. In first you are saying there is no difference, in second you are saying there is.

Comment: sorry, i'm the one. your answer is nothing to do with the question :- originally ... (not about short code, but the variable scope)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/e157d3bc-ab85-476b-89d2-fe1c5d79f95c/view-source

Comment: @RokKralj: actually there is no difference. In case allow_short_tags is on

Answer (score 3):

There is a little difference, that can be very, very annoying. If in php.ini you `short_open_tag` is set to false, you will receive a lot of errors. Otherwise, is exactly the same.

In every case, the last `;` before `?>` is optional.

Answer (score 2):

There is no output differnce between `<?=$x;?>` and `<? echo $x; ?>` for that matter.

Even though i think this technique of including an active PHP file isn't really best practices in this specific condition.

Shai.

Comment: `$test = "hi"; require 'test.php' // $test is in test.php's scope!`. not my downvote though